# How do I test if memcache is running in php without having to save to and load same object from the cache

Tags: php, sqlite, caching, memcached

I want to test memcache is running, not just testing if the extension is loaded but if memcache is actually available and running on the server. Is there anyway to do it aside actually saving a test object to the cache and retrieving it?

What I am thinking of doing use different storage options for my cache based on availability beginning with memcached through sqlite to files.

Answer (score 2):

You are aware that `memcache` requires a server, right? If so, why don't you just try to connect to it and monitor the return value of `connect()`? Returns `FALSE` if it fails to connect to any of the servers provided.

Answer (score 1):

As user1800246 pointed out, you can check the return variable from [Memcache::connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.connect.php):

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$connect = $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211);

if(!$connect){
     throw new Exception('Could not connect to Memcached');
}
```

Comment: This is good but time-expensive. Is there no quicker way, I wonder.